# How to solve the the following integral equation.

Tags: integration, complex-integration

Could anyone help me with solving the following equation, please?

$$ t=\frac{aR^2}{D(C1-C2)}\int_{x1}^{x2}\frac{d\theta}{(1+\cos\theta)^2+[\tan\frac\theta2+8\int_0^\infty \frac{\cosh^2\theta\tau}{\sinh^2\pi\tau}\tanh[\tau(\pi-\theta)]d\tau]}$$

Is it possible to start solving the integration in the denominator using the Trapezoidal rule?, Then solving the total integration of the function. Is that correct as there is variable of $ \theta $ inside the integration in denominator?

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Solve what as a function of what ?

Comment: The problem that I have $ \theta $ in the integration of the denominator.  So, how can I solve the small integration separably?

Comment: @Mak You can treat $\theta$ as a constant within an integral that is with respect to $\tau$

Comment: I want to solve the time as a function of $\theta$ @JeanMarie

Comment: @DBPriGuy Good Idea, That's may be sensible

Comment: @JeanMarie t is a function of $\theta$ and $\tau$ , That why there are two integrals

Comment: The integrand in the integral for $\tau$ acts like $1/\tau$ close to $\tau=0$. Therefore, the integral is diverging there.

Comment: $t$ is neither a function of $\theta$ nor of $\tau$. Both $\tau$ and $\theta$ are "dumb variables". Now I understand: the RHS is a constant (as long as $x_1$ and $x_2$ are constants). Or do you want to take the antiderivative with respect to $\theta$ of the integrand ?

Comment: @Tobias, That right, do I would say to assume it $10^{-4}$

Comment: @JeanMarie, Could you explain your question further, please?

Comment: Do you agree for example that $\tau$ disappears once the integration in the bottom integral has been done ?